# Log in https aspx web page with jsoup

Tags: java, asp.net, authentication, https, jsoup

Is it possible to log in to a https aspx web page using jsoup ?

the page where i try to log in is: https://by.vulog.com/communauto-labs/login.aspx

what i'm tryng to do at the end is to access https://by.vulog.com/communauto-labs/index.aspx in order to parse the html to get some information, but when u try to access this page, i still redirecting me to the login page (I can see that by looking at the html of homePage variable)

Or should I use some other tools ?

Here is the my code wich does not seem to work:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://by.vulog.com/communauto-labs/login.aspx")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        response = Jsoup.connect("https://by.vulog.com/communauto-labs/login.aspx")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginForm$UserName", "my_login")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginForm$Password", "my_password")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("https://by.vulog.com/communauto-labs/index.aspx")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .get();
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use Jsoup?  WebSecurity seems like it would do the same that you want to do, but with more functionality and way less of a headache.

Comment: No particular reason, it was one of the techno that I found after some  research on google, (i'm familiar with java). Do you know a good site to learn web security ?

Comment: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx)  is a good place to start.  Websecurity allows you to add roles, and limit access to certain pages with VERY minimal code.  Once implemented, a simple '@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)' is all you need to verify if someone is logged in.

Comment: to be honest, java is good for certain things, but when it comes to security, it falls short compared to C#, VB, ect.

Comment: Another good site is (http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security)

Comment: *"does not seem to work"* would mean it throws an exception? If yes, please update the post with your stacktrace

Comment: I edit my post to better explain my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggling with the problem, I used a brutal solution :

Connecting through my naviagtor (chrome), using developers tools to get the authetification cookies, and pass them directly to my program before launching it.

I don't like this solution but it's for a single use programm.